# How to run two python programs on MacBook simultaneously?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I was wondering if I need to run two python programs simultaneously, can I open two terminal windows and run each of them at the same time? Will this slow down the computing? If so, is there any way to quickly run several programs at the same time? Like parallel computing. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I open two terminal windows and run each of them at the same time?

*You can do that but they won't run parallelly.*

> Will this slow down the computing?

*If you can run them in a truly parallel way, individual programs should not feel any slower than if they were run sequentially.*

However, if you have multiple python scripts that you wish to run simultaneously in the same terminal, you can type the following lines on your bash terminal:

```sh
python3 script1.py &
python3 script2.py &
```

Or if you want to run them from another python script, you can do this:

```py
# script3.py
import subprocess

subprocess.run("python3 script1.py & python3 script2.py", shell=True)
```

Or if you want to run multiple processes parallelly, you can take a look at python's built in [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

Option1: Check using [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) with [vertical split](http://fungi.yuggoth.org/vsp4s/)

Option2: Download iTerm2 for macOSX from this [link](https://www.iterm2.com/#/section/downloads).